# What is the suitable way to slim multiple similar method?

Tags: c#, structure

Assume that I have 2 similar method named GetFiles() and PutFiles()

```
    public static void GetFiles(string source, string dest)
    {
        using (Session session = new Session())
        {
            session.Open(sessionOptions);

            TransferOptions transferOptions = new TransferOptions();
            transferOptions.TransferMode = TransferMode.Binary;

            TransferOperationResult transferResult;

            ////Different in here////
            transferResult = session.GetFiles(source, dest, false, transferOptions);

            transferResult.Check();

            foreach (TransferEventArgs transfer in transferResult.Transfers)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Transfer file from {0} to {1}", source, dest);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void PutFiles(string source, string dest)
    {
        using (Session session = new Session())
        {
            session.Open(sessionOptions);

            TransferOptions transferOptions = new TransferOptions();
            transferOptions.TransferMode = TransferMode.Binary;

            TransferOperationResult transferResult;

            ////Different in here////
            transferResult = session.PutFiles(source, dest, false, transferOptions);

            transferResult.Check();

            foreach (TransferEventArgs transfer in transferResult.Transfers)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Transfer file from {0} to {1}", source, dest);
            }
        }
    }
```

You could see they are totally same except called different function inside the method
I have consider add a new method named Transfer File, which accept one more parameter to control process of put file/get file

```
    public static void TransferFile(string source, string dest, bool GetFile)
    {
        using (Session session = new Session())
        {
            session.Open(sessionOptions);

            TransferOptions transferOptions = new TransferOptions();
            transferOptions.TransferMode = TransferMode.Binary;

            TransferOperationResult transferResult;

            if(GetFile)
            transferResult = session.GetFiles(source, dest, false, transferOptions);
            else
            transferResult = session.PutFiles(source, dest, false, transferOptions);

            transferResult.Check();

            foreach (TransferEventArgs transfer in transferResult.Transfers)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Transfer file from {0} to {1}", source, dest);
            }
        }
    }
```

But later on I found that this is not a best solution, because I it can't handle more than 2 condition(get file & put files)

Comment: What do you mean it can't handle more than 2 conditions?

Comment: If I have one more function as -
transferResult = session.CompareFiles(source, dest, false, transferOptions); , then I would have to change the parameter of TransferFile(string source, string dest, bool GetFile) to TransferFile(string source, string dest, int FileAction) so I could handle more different process

Comment: But I don't think this solution is good at all

Comment: I mean I think it is a pretty good solution. You've identified repeat functionality and factored it into a single method, thereby enforcing the Don't Repeat Yourself (DRY) principle.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this,

```
public static void Get_Or_Put_Files(string source, string dest, bool isFilesAreGetting)
{
    using (Session session = new Session())
    {
        session.Open(sessionOptions);

        TransferOptions transferOptions = new TransferOptions();
        transferOptions.TransferMode = TransferMode.Binary;

        TransferOperationResult transferResult;

        if(isFilesAreGetting)
        {
            transferResult = session.GetFiles(source, dest, false, transferOptions);
        }
        else
        {
            transferResult = session.PutFiles(source, dest, false, transferOptions);
        }

        transferResult.Check();

        foreach (TransferEventArgs transfer in transferResult.Transfers)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Transfer file from {0} to {1}", source, dest);
        }
    }
}
```

Simply add an extra parameter to tell whether this method is Getting or Putting your files.

Comment: Thanks, but that's what I've proposed, I'm wondering if there are any better solution.

Comment: But i don't think so that a better solution is exists none other than this.